# How to interpolate and fill in the blanks of this table by interpolation in Octave?

Tags: octave, interpolation

I have a table like this:

[image: Table]

and I have to interpolate this by using Octave. How can I do it?

Comment: If you have the data in octave format, use [`interp1`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/interp1.html) or sth. If your "table" is _literally an image of a table_, then I'm afraid the answer is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Please provide at least a copy-paste-able piece of code instead of a screenshot. *How* do you want to interpolate that data? What kind of function do you expect it to follow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want just 1d interpolation `interp1` is usually the way to go. For example the spline interpolation looks not too bad:

[image]

Here's the code:

[image]

Comment: I feel the need to point out that you should be wary using a spline fit for such sparse data. You're adding curves that probably aren't really there. But it does look nice

Comment: @SardarUsama: Next time I would like to see an answer as GIF where you write it on a chalkboard :-)

Comment: The sarcasm here is funny, refreshing even! @V150, in case you didn't catch the joke, please [format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on stackoverflow so that it is easier for others to help you!

Comment: @Andy There's 3 lines of code in the bottom image which, if nicely formatted, would be at least 6 lines? I wasn't having a dig at the answer anyway, my comment tags the OP :)